# Cannot render the successfully routed view in Backbone App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my ongoing self thought process by building [my simple blog app](http://jsfiddle.net/farukscan/62Lo2qes/8/) I am finding solutions to problems and encountering new ones.

Now successfully routing to a second view from a first one. But page is not populated by the new views html.

a routes hash and route method from the router definition I use: fiddle line:75 on.

```
routes: {
        '/posts/postform': 'viewPostForm',
        '': 'viewPosts'
    },

    viewPostForm: function(){
    console.log("router method viewPostForm have been reached.");
    this.postformview = new postFormView();
    //!!the call of render and appending el of view to a the toplevel el defined at router may be neccesssary.
    $(this.body).html( this.postformview.render().el );
}
```

definition of the postformview: fiddle line: 54.

```
var postFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $('#postFormTemplate').html() ),

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template() );//?where in dom zis the this.el
        return this;
    }
});
```

What is the missing thing?

Comment: Are you certain this method is firing in response to a route being hit?

Comment: In your code `this.body` is - ?

Comment: this.body was set in the router def by body: 'body' attribute for having views more independent of dom and having all this dependency in router.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `postFormView`?

Comment: Updated by adding postformview def. Sorry for the formatting, away from the keybiard i am best at.

Comment: did you check to see if you're actually reaching the router's method?

Comment: I am uncertain. I have added a `console.log("router method have been reached.")`. But cannot see it at the console when I click the link. Only url in the address bar is updated expectedly. What is the reason?

Comment: It seems it is not reached. why?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `/` at the beginning of the url for the method creates and renders second view in the routes hash will make it work.

```
routes: {
    'posts/postform': 'viewPostForm',
    '': 'viewPosts'
},
```